# What are the important values of GNSS antennas

Tags: antenna, gnss

I want to compare different GNSS antennas, but I don't really know what values to compare.

How can I compare them with datasheets looking like [this?](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/ANN-MB_DataSheet_%28UBX-18049862%29.pdf)

Edit:
The antenne will be used on a rover that will move off-road.
I need maximum precision at all times (I do use RTK.)

Comment: Well it depends on what you'll use them for, and with what kind of device – no general answer can be given.

Comment: They give you gain, impedance, radiation patterns...what is important to your design?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited my Question with the use-case!